# What Unsupported docker v2 repository request for 'artifactory' means

Tags: docker, artifactory

My docker client/server version is:

```
$ docker version
Client:
Version:           18.09.0
API version:       1.39
Go version:        go1.10.4
Git commit:        4d60db4
Built:             Wed Nov  7 00:49:01 2018
OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
Engine:
Version:          18.09.0
API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.12)
Go version:       go1.10.4
Git commit:       4d60db4
Built:            Wed Nov  7 00:16:44 2018
OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
Experimental:     false
```

Would like to use artifactory to host dockers.
When running

```
docker login
```

getting:

> Unsupported docker v2 repository request for 'artifactory'

What does this error mean?

What V2 part is artifactory complaining on?

Comment: have you set everything up correctly? https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Getting+Started+with+Artifactory+as+a+Docker+Registry

Comment: more digging into this, one of the following is missing - reverse proxy, or - creating cert to use https instead of http

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ensure you have the following rewrite in your reverse proxy.

Nginx

```
  rewrite ^/(v1|v2)/(.*) /api/docker/$repo/$1/$2;
```

Apache

```
    RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" "^/(v1|v2)/"
```

This requirement is currently [missing from the jfrog documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+NGINX), however it is documented if you go into HTTP settings and let artifactory generate the proxy config for you.

[image]

Comment: could you supply for haproxy too?

Comment: I get an error with Artfiactory 7.11.5 saying the "repo" variable is unknown when restarting nginx.

Comment: UPDATE: This is actually not needed with 7.11.5. I had the `docker pull` command incorrect and it was going to the wrong sub-path. Looks like Artifactory supports the repository path without that rewrite now.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the error with reverse proxy, this message also appears when you try to push an image into a non-existent repository.

Look for HTTP 404 in Artifactory request.log

Comment: Depending on your Artifactory configuration, make sure to add the repository name as well when pushing and tagging images: `docker push artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory-repo/myimage`

Answer (score 0):

I will add: at least in version 7.5.7 there is a check in Docker repository settings to "Block pushing of image manifest v2 schema 1", in my case unchecking it solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it's because of docker http settings keep default "repository path", while I'm trying to push using subdomain.